# Delphi projects always opens same .pas files

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

Every time I open the project, it opens the same `.pas` files. Even if I close those files and open some other files, when I close and reopen the project, the same original files will be opened. How can I solve this?

Comment: Is your project desktop file (`<Project>.dsk`) readonly?

Comment: Nops. Has a normal `Archive` attribute.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: My interpretation of the question is that it's not that the IDE is reopening the project with the files that were open when it was closed, but that it's always opening with the same files, regardless of which files were open when it was last closed. That's not a feature, I think, it's not supposed to do that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just close Delphi, delete .dsk file, reopen project.
Be sure to select autosave options properly in Tools -> Options -> Environment Options.